# Distinguish suggested tags with a comma when asking a new question

Tags: feature-request, tags

I have noticed when asking a question that the 'Tags' area of all Stack Exchange sites are not shown in a clear format:

> [image]

There are no commas separating the different Tags which may cause confusion to a new user.

Comment: I suspect this would be marked as status-bydesign, but we've moved it to MSO since this applies to the entire network of sites.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I totally see what you're getting at now and agree this could be confusing.

Comment: I turned this into feature request, feel free to roll back if you don't think it's proper.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That's awesome, cheers bud

Answer (score 6):

Email is one tag, communication is another.

The tags shown are picked randomly from our pool of tags, will pick a different selection each time. From what I can tell it always chooses three tags.

The software-industry is shown as such as that is how the tag is done. Presumably because you can't have spaces in a tag or its unsure if it is one tag or two separate tags of software and industry.

A potential alternative would be to split them with *or* and a comma.

> at least one tag such as(software-industry, email or communication), max 5 tags

Comment: bounty awarded to recover voting and chat privileges that were given up to [support community effort](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10706605#10706605 "respective discussion at Workplace and Programmers chat rooms")

Answer (score 2):

The "Tags" part is not outdated, [[software-industry]](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-industry), [[email]](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email), and [[communication]](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication) are 3 valid tags in https://workplace.stackexchange.com/.

I guess it's the fact that the 3 tags are *separated by spaces* in the "Tag" part that is confusing.<sup>†</sup> *Tag names cannot contain spaces* (can't find a guideline that says so, but that's how it is) so the `email communication` in the given example is not the [email communication] tag, but two separate tags – [email] and [communication].

I do agree with [RhysW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185337/225020) that separating the tags by comma would be more intuitive.

<sup>†</sup>  Though if you're using the 3 tags, that's one way you'd type it. First tag, then <kbd>Space</kbd>, second tag, then <kbd>Space</kbd>, etc.

Comment: I was looking from the Workplace SE only thinking that it was [Email Communication] not [Email-Communication] or what you've suggested.

Comment: @MichaelGrubey, sorry can you clarify what you mean by your comment? I don't understand.

Comment: I thought the tags that were displayed were only native to the Workplace SE, not every other SE site.

Comment: @MichaelGrubey, the [email communication] tag does not exist on any of the SE sites, because spaces are not allowed in tag names. You are right about tags displayed being native to their respective sites (at least from what I can see in Meta SO, Stack Overflow, and Super User). I hope I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: Yeah you are right in getting my drift. If you look at it from a new users point of view - asking their first question ever it can be misleading and they end up trying to post tags they think are relevant or allowed when they're not.

Comment: @MichaelGrubey, Yeah, that's why I think putting commas there is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree about using a comma. But indeed it could be phrased a bit different.

When entering, tags can be separated by a space. Though a comma is accepted too, it's not needed, which is especially useful on mobile. So: an example showing multiple tags should show a space too, as that's the easiest way to enter tags.

I feel that what you're seeing is indeed an example of *multiple* tags:

> at least one tag such as (objective-c wpf arrays), max 5 tags

...to me, is short for:

> Enter at least one tag, at most five tags, such as for example: objective-c wpf arrays

...but could indeed easily be made less confusing using something like:

> at least 1 tag, at most 5 tags, like: objective-c wpf arrays

[image]